# Spring LDAP, Is it possible to configure LdapTemplate using authenticated use?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ldap

In my application I have fill some user fields from its information in a LDAP, I use LdapTemplate configured in the servlet-context.xml (with a properties file to set the values) and everything works perfect but I don't want to have the login of a user set in plain text in the application so I wonder if it is possible to configure the LDAPTemplate using the user logged in the application and if possible get a way to do it.

My actual configuration is this:

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
    <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}" />
    <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userDn}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to set the password for instance as that isn't available in plain text (at least it shouldn't be!!!). So that will become an issue. Also are you sure you want to do that because that would also mean that each time you access LDAP you need to setup a connection which is quite some overhead.

Comment: Probably I expressed myself wrong, when I said password in plain text I mean the password that I have already configured in the properties file. My aim is not to have any password nor userDn configured and use, if it is possible, the user currently logged with spring-security. But I didn't realize about the overhead this could imply.

Comment: I was refering to the password of the current user... If you need a username/password to authenticate you cannot do that as you don't have the cleartext password of that user (at least you shouldn't have). Also why is this an issue, set the correct rights on the property file so only the appliation and selected users can access it the content. Are you by any change use Spring Security?

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring Security to authenticate the user in the application against the LDAP, the same LDAP where I want to search for information for other users.

In my current approach I configure the LdapTemplate using plain text for the userDn and password, because this is actually the only way I know to do it. I don't know if it is mandatory to use the pair of user/password or if it is possible to configure the LdapTemplate somehow to use the user who is authenticated once is 'sent' to authenticate against the LDAP using spring security.